# If bruteforcing a password goes aaa, AAA, aab, AAB, etc, all the way to ZZZ, wouldn't ZZZZZZ be the most secure password?

Tags: passwords

I'm only taking about security against bruteforce attacks.

I assume that most crackers start at `a` and go up to `zzzzzzz` for as long as instructed (so it could be `zzzzzzzzzzz` if told so in the programming), as randomly guessing, storing the list of guesses, generating a new random guess, checking it against the list of old guesses and trying if it hasn't been guessed would be inefficient. Also, `ZZZZZZZZZZ` is very unlikely to be in a dictionary attack.

Using that logic, wouldn't `ZZZZZZZZZZ` be the most secure password out of all passwords that are 10 or less characters?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, you also attach a weight to each password, so that "password" is first, maybe throw in some randomization into which one is next

Comment: But `ZZZZZZZZZZ` wouldn't be in a word-list for a dictionary attack.

Comment: That assumes that the attacker behaves like you proposed. What if they start with a random password, run until `ZZZ` jump to `aaa` until they're at the start?

Comment: @chipperyman573: I just checked in my big list of previously leaked passwords that I would use in a penetration test as a word-list against hashed passwords. "ZZZZZZZZZZ" is in there, so if you chose that and I had your password hash, I'd break it in considerably less than a second in the pre-cracked passwords run.

Comment: Possible extension of the question: does it make sense for a random password to have a non-random first character (since 0, 1, a, A, z, Z would probably be brute forced early, hence reducing the time it takes for a *strong* password)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The attacker is in your head.** By this I mean that the attacker knows you and knows your password generation strategies. If you systematically use passwords beginning with a 'Z', then he will start his search with such passwords. (Especially since you have described this very method on a publicly readable Web site.)

You *might* have an edge if you choose your passwords differently from everybody else; but attackers adapt, and adapt *fast*. Choosing 'ZZZZZZZZZZ' as password is strong only as long as attackers try potential passwords in alphabetical order; and attackers have already stopped doing that. They first try passwords with "structure", such as ten repetitions of the same letter, because that's a kind of passwords that human users choose (then they continue with derivations from common words and names).

It is hard to outsmart attackers; it is especially hard to *know* how much you outsmarted attackers, because smartness is not something that is readily quantified and measured. The normal stance is to *assume* that the attackers knows everything about your password generation process, save the random choices within that process; this is the only way you can reliably estimate the strength of your password.

Regardless of how you choose your password, an attacker who is intent on trying all possible letter combinations can always generate these combinations in a random order, which guarantees him the theoretical average success rate of *N/2* (if there are *N* possible passwords, he will try on average half of them before hitting the right one). There is no password generation method which can be used to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

The assumption that password crackers go from a to ZZZZZZZZZZ is probably incorrect. Password crackers have evolved to use much more complex techniques that extend to using [markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain) etc. To get a better idea of what professionals do when attemting to crack a password read this great article:

[Anatomy of a hack: How crackers ransack passwords like “qeadzcwrsfxv1331”](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/how-crackers-make-minced-meat-out-of-your-passwords/)

Even in the case where they did enumerate from a to ZZZZZZZZ it should not take a pro long to get to ZZZZZZZZZZ given the processing power they have at their disposal and the limited length and key space of the example you provided.

Comment: "it should not take a pro long to get to ZZZZZZZZZZ" this is it, the bottom line is that if they are bruteforceing it (cracking a hash), it may take a bit longer to get to ZZZZZZZZZZ than AAAAAAAAAA but they will get there before too long anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Only the most simple bruteforce would work that way. A much better use of your time would be to add an extra character.

If you go here http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/ there is a calculator that demonstrates how much password length matters. For example, using only upper/lower case alpha, md5, a 10 character password takes 531 years to brute force. A 11 character password takes 27652 years under the same conditions.

Comment: This site explains it very well, as well: https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm